# Mouseover color of ComboBox item

Tags: wpf, combobox

I've created a `combobox` in my WPF project and applied the following style:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#005578"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#005578"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ComboBoxItem.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#96A51E"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

When the combobox is "closed" it shall display the selected item in #005578 (dark blue).
When the combox is "opened" it shall display all items in #005578 and the item  the mouse cursor is pointing at in #96A51E (yellow)

Unfortunately, the mouseover color is a darker shade of blue (darker than #05578) instead of yellow as you can see here:

[[image: ComboBox[1]]
Why is it like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you have this problem is because you're changing the style but not the template. That does a mouseover effect itself.
You would need to replace that with a more suitable one.
I'm using win 10 and if I extract the template for comboboxitem I see:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxItemControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="False"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#1F26A0DA"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#A826A0DA"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"/>
                <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#3D26A0DA"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FF26A0DA"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#2E0080FF"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#99006CD9"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"/>
                <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="False"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#3DDADADA"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FFDADADA"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"/>
                <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FF26A0DA"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#5426A0DA"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FF26A0DA"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

You would need to consider how this is to work when the item is selected, not selected etc.